# How can I solve syntax error in yaml file when pushing to github?

Tags: django, postgresql, yaml

I'm using postgresql with django. I set a github action that verifies my code whenever I push or pull, and I get the following error:
`You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 19`
Here is my yaml:

```
# This workflow will install Python dependencies, run tests and lint with a single version of Python
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-python-with-github-actions

name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: github_actions
          
        ports:
          - 5433:5432
          
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.9.7
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: "3.9.7"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Test with Unittest
      env:
        SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
        EMAIL_FROM_USER: ${{secrets.EMAIL_FROM_USER}}
        EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD}}
        DB_NAME: ${{secrets.DB_NAME}}
        DB_USER: ${{secrets.DB_USER}}
        DB_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DB_PASSWORD}}
        DB_HOST: ${{secrets.DB_HOST}}
        DB_ENGINE: ${{secrets.DB_ENGINE}}
        DB_PORT: ${{secrets.DB_PORT}}
      run: |
        python3 manage.py test
```

line 19 corresponds to `image: postgres:14` but I can't see any syntax error here. I've looked at some examples and it looks exactly the same.

Comment: What if you wrap it in a string, so `"postgres:14"`?

Comment: I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub actions, configuring a Django web app service container using the Docker Hub for postgres images works fine with this code only.

```
image: postgres
```

For your particular case, you can check if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get the same error.

Comment: What if you write port 5432:5432

Comment: Exactly the same error. I also removed the quotations around ```python-version: 3.9.7``` but I still get the error.

Comment: you have configured psycopg2 and added all dependencies in requirements like in this post https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/github-actions-in-action-setting-up-django-and-postgres

Comment: Thanks rs_punia, I think I was missing some dependencies, I re-did it following your post and it's working now!

Comment: Good to know that. You can answer this question with the steps you followed. May be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, I followed these two posts that are up to date:
https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/github-actions-in-action-setting-up-django-and-postgres

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04

Make sure you install all the dependencies.
I also set the port to 5432 and image to `postgres:14.2`
(To know your postrgesql version you can enter `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres -V`)
See final yml file:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:14.2
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: github_action
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Test with Unittest
      env:
        SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
        EMAIL_FROM_USER: ${{secrets.EMAIL_FROM_USER}}
        EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD}}
        DB_NAME: ${{secrets.DB_NAME}}
        DB_USER: ${{secrets.DB_USER}}
        DB_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DB_PASSWORD}}
        DB_HOST: ${{secrets.DB_HOST}}
        DB_ENGINE: ${{secrets.DB_ENGINE}}
        DB_PORT: ${{secrets.DB_PORT}}
      run: |
        python3 manage.py test
```